# Encrypting url with addon

Tags: url, encryption, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I want to know whether it is possible to encrypt the url shown in a browser.For e.g if i install an addon called stackoverflow addon , can i encrypt the url so that when users type stackoverflow.com , some random string is shown in the browser but the actual stackoverflow site is shown.The aim of this method would be to bypass web filters.

Hope you guys can give me some insights about how this can be achieve .

P.S i am a beginner with addons but its never late to learn

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create some add-on that obfuscates what URI is shown to the user. There are quite a bunch of possible ways from manipulating the UI to rewriting URIs internally.

However, this does not affect web filters at all. Web filters (usually) run not within the Firefox process, but outside, more often than not as some kind of (transparent) proxy on another system. So any obfuscation within Firefox would not be visible to the web filter anyway and it would still filter.

If you really want to bypass web filters, then you'd have to use some kind of VPN and/or proxy. But that is not strictly a Firefox related question, or an add-on related one.

Comment: This is heartbreaking :( .You have any suitable solution .The thing is that i already have a web proxy and its already blocked at some places.I was hoping that with addon i could "unblock" it :P

Answer (score 0):

In firefox:
There is a solution. You can listen to url bar change and based create some encrypting algortihm and just the url visusually in the url bar. However if user sniffs it http headers they wont see the encrypted url. This is only a visual solution:

There's a function called `setCurrentURI` on the `webNavigation`/`docShell` object. It's a funky one, I never found a real use for it. But it does exactly what you need.

```
gBrowser.webNavigation.setCurrentURI(Services.io.newURI('about:blank', null, null))
```

setting it to `about:blank` blanks it out, you can set it to any url though, it won't change the page, just the url.

so listen to page `DOMContentLoaded` of that new tab, and as soon as it loads run this code. maybe can change it even faster, like detect when the value of the input box changes. So you listen to tab DOMContentLoaded like this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Code_snippets%2FTabbed_browser#Detecting_page_load